# How can i overcome 'Error: Zone already loaded' conflicts with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, squarespace, zonejs

I have developed a simple Angular app built using Angular CLI that is designed to be embedded within third party websites. It works fine on a demo site in production mode.

However, when the app is included within a website running on [Squarespace](http://squarespace.com) i get the following error:

```
Uncaught d {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Zone already loaded.
at d (https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5804a95d5016e1b3e34d642…}
```

I have ensured that my packaged Angular app script is only being included once.

I can only presume that the Squarespace CMS is already including the Zone.js library for some reason with one on their scripts?

How can i prevent this kind of conflict? Surely it must be possible to run an Angular2 app along side other scripts that could possibly use the Zone.js dependency?

If anyone can shed any light on this, that would be much appreciated.

Running:
Angular @ 2.4.0
zone.js @ 0.7.7

Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution and have written a short post to explain. [https://medium.com/@cliffers/how-to-run-multiple-webpack-instances-on-the-same-page-and-avoid-any-conflicts-4e2fe0f016d1](https://medium.com/@cliffers/how-to-run-multiple-webpack-instances-on-the-same-page-and-avoid-any-conflicts-4e2fe0f016d1)

Comment: Did you find an angular-cli solution?

Comment: This happened to me because although the script was deployed, once the page was loading the previously deployed script which led to a conflict. Ensure there isn't anyway the script can be loaded twice - clear deployed artefacts first before deploying