# ASP.net MVC and Angular 4 - Zone already loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-cli

**Application Background**: My application is built up using ASP.net MVC(.net framework 4.6) and several Angular 4 mini SPAs

Shared view _Layout.cshtml have one mini SPA to show shopping basket contents and it is referenced using:

```
<script src="~/apps/shopping/inline.2785c74270c160e8df55.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/shopping/polyfills.35726d60cdf25fecc5f1.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/shopping/vendor.4918fe9ed7ea45b90ec8.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/shopping/main.4d6729c54eca7c31dbba.bundle.js"></script>
```

Another view Order.cshtml have another SPA and it is referenced using:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/apps/userorder/inline.2a63d25fd80947ce8bb4.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/userorder/polyfills.35726d60cdf25fecc5f1.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/userorder/vendor.ec246c0701440a3e2ce3.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/apps/userorder/main.46be1befa8a20148f402.bundle.js"></script>}
```

**Error**

1. All looks good when I am at home view because on that page only 1 SPA is loaded
2. When I go to order view, I see below error in console window because now 2 SPAs have been loaded but still it works functionally.

[image]

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539516/how-can-i-overcome-error-zone-already-loaded-conflicts-with-angular) and [this](https://medium.com/@cliffers/how-to-run-multiple-webpack-instances-on-the-same-page-and-avoid-any-conflicts-4e2fe0f016d1)

I am using Angular 4 with Angular CLI. Could anyone help me to get past this error, please?

Comment: Your polyfill JS also contains bundled ZONE.js library that was already loaded by previous script

Comment: Thanks for your response! What solution would you suggest? I tried removing zone.js from package.json but somehow it still get bundled up in polyfill.

Comment: @VadimB Could you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have aswer. It depends on how your bundler is designed. All you need - exclude zone from one of bundled scripts.

Comment: I am using all default configuration of angular CLI and internally it use webpack. Would that help?

Comment: The issue in your polyfill - for some reason it also include this library.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out import statement for zone in polyfill.ts and it worked like a charm.
[image]